# EXEC sp_executesql - capture RETURN value and OUTPUT value from stored procedure call

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-executesql

Given a simple stored procedure, that populates a `OUTPUT` parameter and also `RETURN`s a value, such as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test 
(
    @param_out INT OUTPUT
)
AS BEGIN
    SELECT @param_out = 9
    RETURN 2
END
```

How can I call this procedure using `sp_executesql` and capture both of these values?

I've tried:

```
DECLARE @ret INT, @param_out INT
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL N'EXEC @ret = sp_test',
    N'@ret INT OUTPUT, @param_out INT OUTPUT',
    @ret OUTPUT,
    @param_out OUTPUT

SELECT @ret, @param_out
```

However this complains that `@param_out` was not supplied:

> *Procedure or function 'sp_test' expects parameter '@param_out', which was not supplied.*

Comment: Why are you wrapping the call in `sp_executesql` anyway?

Comment: I'm actually dynamically building up the stored procedure name as a string, this was just an example to demonstrate the issues I was having with the OUTPUT and RETURN values.

Comment: So you don't need `sp_executesql` for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to pass both values as `OUTPUT` parameters to `sp_executesql` as well:

```
DECLARE @ret int,
        @param_out int;
EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC @ret = sp_test @param_out OUT;',
                   N'@ret INT OUTPUT, @param_out INT OUTPUT',
                   @ret OUTPUT,
                   @param_out OUTPUT;

SELECT @ret,
       @param_out;
```

I must ask though, why do you want to do this? There's nothing dynamic about this SQL, so why are you using `sp_executesql`? I also advise against using the return value of an SP; you should really be using another `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: Adding that the stored procedure return code should be used to indicate success or warning/error, not to return data.

Comment: Perfect, I see my mistake quite clearly now that you've pointed it out. Your right, there's nothing dynamic about this example, but I actually dynamically build up the procedure to call in my 'real' SQL. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `sp_executesql` here just because the stored procedure name is dynamic.

The [`EXEC` grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) accepts `@module_name_var`.

You can do

```
DECLARE @ret       INT,
        @param_out INT
DECLARE @procname SYSNAME = 'sp_test'

EXEC @ret = @procname
  @param_out OUTPUT
```

and the procedure with the name in `@procname` will be executed